# Converting continuous variable dict to binary variables in python docplex

Tags: optimization, python, cplex, docplex

I am solving a problem using linear relaxation at the initial phase. Hence, I need continuous variables at the beginning. Then I need to convert some continuous variables to binary and solve the same problem in that way. If I need to redefine the model, it can be very inefficient as I have many constraints.

I have defined a continuous variable as follows:

```
#Define sets
X = [(i, j) for i in range(1, a + 1) for j in range(1, b + 1)]

# Define variables
x = m.continuous_var_dict(X, name="x", lb=0, ub=1)
```

Is it possible to convert it to binary variable, possible in the most efficient way computationally?

Comment: Do it the other way around: use binary variables and then form a relaxation (docplex.mp.relax_linear).

Comment: Cant you just code it as  x = m.binary_var_dict()?. Else define $ z_{i,j}$ as binary & add constrs $ x_{i,j} = z_{i,j}$

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen that sounds logical. I did this: relaxed_model = LinearRelaxer.make_relaxed_model(model)
relaxed_model.solve(). However, after solving the model, when I try to store, let's say, x variables, it says that the model is not solved yet. I saw some iterative methods, however as I have too many variables it could take some time. How do you think I can obtain the result of x variables as a result of the relaxed model most efficiently? What would you suggest using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485310/how-to-convert-a-float-to-a-binary-variable-in-docplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to convert a variable into another type, this can be possible by using ilo.conversation method. This can be invoked on DoCplex by;

```
The_defined_variable.set_vartype('C')
```

Where the character "C" would be as well as either "B", "I" or "N" to convert continues, binary, integer or semi-defined variables respectively. Also, if you are willing to solve the relaxed version of the problem the simple below template would be helpful:

```
!pip install cplex
!pip install docplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.relax_linear import LinearRelaxer

m = Model("model")
'''
optimization model    
'''

lp = LinearRelaxer.make_relaxed_model(m)
lp.print_information()
s_lp = lp.solve(log_output=True)
s_lp.display()
```

As an example of how these two method work please, see this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RemT_UUaE4kkvIZ85M1BeHfSTRaAJybW?usp=sharing).

Comment: set_vartype method does not work, raising this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'set_vartype'. Do you know if it has applicability in variable dictionaries as well? And is it efficient? @A.Omidi

Comment: @madetolast, I coded the problem with those and the model worked fine. At the moment I don't remember I used dic or any type of definition, but as far as I know this is not an issue. I will check it and tell you ASAP.

Comment: That would be great! I'll be waiting for your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @madetolast,  I just updated my answer.